# Android- overlay button from fragment Toolbar is clipped

Tags: android, android-fragments

Idea: I want a button to be drawn as overlay from a Toolbar like this:
[image]

The Toolbar is actually a fragments view and the background is Activity.
Here is fragments xml:

```
...
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/bluebox"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:clipChildren="false">         <----- Define clipping false

        <Button
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:id="@+id/bpkicker"
            android:background="@drawable/whitecircle"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"   <--- Over the view edge
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:onClick="goToCurrentLocation"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
...
```

In the fragments onCreateView I animate the fragments y coordinate to a certain height. (I only want the Toolbar to be shown from the bottom of the screen when app is opened. It will follow the users finger for sliding up or is kicked up once the button is pressed).

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(buildingPageView, "y", USEABLE_HEIGHT, USEABLE_HEIGHT-TOOLBAR_HEIGHT-VIRT_NAV_BAR);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.start();
```

The Problem is that the button is still clipped. I believe the problem is that android thinks that the toolbar is in the top of the screen and thus there is nowhere to draw the button.

On the left is android studio implementation and on the right is the app itself:
[image: Left is android studio implementation, right is the app]

Why ise the button clipped?

Comment: place the button outside the toolbar in your layout.

Comment: I'm afraid I have tried that case as well. The problem with that is that Button is drawn under toolbar even thou it is wirtten after the toolbar in xml. The other problem is that when I set topBottom -25dp it pushes the button over the top edge of toolbar but creates a new white space in the relative layout they are both in.

Comment: Hey mate, did you manage to make this working somehow? I'm having the same issue but no answer so far.

Comment: Hey, no elegant solutions still. I was forced to hack it together. Made one button on the action screen that was left behind the fragment. Made another on the fragment that was cut with the fragment edge. Positioning those two just right I managed to make it look like one button. I also gave the two buttons the same onClick method. Ugly but works :)